# AngularJS controller syntax - difference between array and function version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am new to AngularJS. What is difference between a controller declared with an array parameter, listing the dependencies both as strings and as JavaScript names,

```
app.controller("firstController", ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'HttpService', 'FisrtSharedService', 'SecondSharedService', function($scope, $modal, $log, HttpService, FisrtSharedService, SecondSharedService) {

}]);
```

...and this form, listing just the JavaScript names?

```
app.controller("firstController", function($scope, $modal, $log, HttpService, FisrtSharedService, SecondSharedService){

});
```

Why the weird syntax in the first version?

Comment: No functional difference. The one using [] is to allow a minified version to be read correctly.

Answer (score 12):

It's used when you minified JS files. `'$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'HttpService',    'FisrtSharedService', 'SecondSharedService'` just declares injectors.

```
app.controller("firstController", ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'HttpService',    'FisrtSharedService', 'SecondSharedService', function($scope, $modal, $log, HttpService, FisrtSharedService, SecondSharedService) {

}]);
```

You also declare injectors like this:

```
firstController.$inject = ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'HttpService',    'FisrtSharedService', 'SecondSharedService'];
app.controller("firstController", function($scope, $modal, $log, HttpService,  FisrtSharedService, SecondSharedService){

});
```